# EF Core 3.1 Query Performance

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-3.0

I am learning asp.net core mvc 3.1. And can't understand why my query is so slow.
Here is the generated query by EFCore (copied from DebugConsole)

```
SELECT [p].[TagID], 
   [p].[CategoryID], 
   [p].[PicID], 
   [p].[TagSysType], 
   [p].[TagDescription], 
   [p].[TagPriority], 
   [p].[TagName], 
   [p].[TagTypeID], 
   [p].[PeriodID], 
   [p].[LinkID], 
   [p].[SourceID], 
   [p0].[LinkID], 
   [p0].[LinkLongName], 
   [p0].[LinkName], 
   [p1].[PeriodID], 
   [p1].[PeriodName], 
   [s].[SourceID], 
   [s].[CategoryID], 
   [s].[SourceName], 
   [s].[SourcePriority], 
   [p2].[TagTypeID], 
   [p2].[TagTypeName], 
   [e].[PicID], 
   [e].[PicName], 
   [c].[CategoryID], 
   [c].[CategoryGroupID], 
   [c].[CategoryName], 
   [a].[TagID], 
   [a].[Cost], 
   [a].[Scale], 
   [a].[Date], 
   [a].[Partner]
   FROM [Tag] AS [p]
          INNER JOIN [Link] AS [p0] ON [p].[LinkID] = [p0].[LinkID]
          INNER JOIN [Period] AS [p1] ON [p].[PeriodID] = [p1].[PeriodID]
          INNER JOIN [Source] AS [s] ON [p].[SourceID] = [s].[SourceID]
          INNER JOIN [TagType] AS [p2] ON [p].[TagTypeID] = [p2].[TagTypeID]
          LEFT JOIN [Pic] AS [e] ON [p].[PicID] = [e].[PicID]
          INNER JOIN [Category] AS [c] ON [p].[CategoryID] = [c].[CategoryID]
          LEFT JOIN [Sale] AS [a] ON [p].[TagID] = [a].[TagID]
```

Result of this query contains about 10000 rows and I need them all in my app (without filtering). Problem is execution time of this query which is about 25 seconds. I thought its too complex query (with a lot of JOINs) for net core technology or awful database architecture, But when I run this query in SQL Studio Management it executes almost instantly if my app in studio is stopped. If my app is running, execution time of query in SQL Studio Management takes about 25 seconds as well. 
App (Net core 3.1) and database (SQL2008) works on one server (Win2012).

Why this happening?

My action in Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.PagingVisible = false;

        IQueryable<Tag> tags = _context.Tag
                                .Include(s => s.Link)
                                .Include(s => s.Period)
                                .Include(s => s.Source)
                                .Include(s => s.TagType)
                                .Include(s => s.Pic);
                                .Include(s => s.Category);
                                .Include(s => s.Sale);

        return PartialView("_SearchResult", tags.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: So what is you app doing to the database?

Comment: Give code working with db

Comment: @Magnus I am using Database First approach and I don't planing to edit data in DB.